# How does sample size selection happen which is generally used as $20\times (p+q)$?

Tags: machine-learning, references, sample-size, learning

Can anyone explain me about how sample size selection happens which is generally used as $20\times (p+q)$? Here $p$ is the number of parameters in the final model and $q $ is the number of parameters that may have been examined but discarded along the way.

Any credible reference is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Check if the edit I did is okay or not.

Comment: Could you provide some background or a source for this formula?  It's an interesting but unfamiliar one, so having some context would help.

Comment: @User1865345
Thanks a lot

Comment: Let me be clear. You got the formula apparently from somewhere and yet you are seeking a reference. Perhaps a clarification is needed.

Comment: @User1865345
Yes I am seeking for reference for this formula. Please help me out if you can

Comment: @whuber I need a reference. A Journal paper or book reference is more appreciated

Comment: It seems to be a quote of a comment by Frank Harrell on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78289/neural-network-modeling-sample-size

Comment: @Henry
Yes I have seen this but I need a reference. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: This comment was not intended to be authoritative, I am sure: it was offered as general guidance for assessing whether your thinking about sample sizes might be hugely wrong.  Please don't take it as a general rule of thumb or universally applicable.  IMHO, its principal merit lies in directing your attention to the number of parameters "that may have been examined but [were] discarded along the way."